# How to transform array of objects for SectionList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following array structure from my API service

```
[
  {
    id: 1001,
    orderNo: 'abc',
    customer: 'John',
    date: 1524526218641
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    orderNo: 'def',
    customer: 'Ringo',
    date: 1524555627191
  },
  {
    id: 1003,
    orderNo: 'ghi',
    customer: 'George',
    date: 1524555662611
  },
  {
    id: 1004,
    orderNo: 'jkl',
    customer: 'Paul',
    date: 1524717318641
  }
]
```

According to [react-native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) I need transform my original array structure from the API service to:

```
[
  {
    title: '23/4/2018',
    data: [
      {
        id: 1001,
        orderNo: 'abc',
        customer: 'John',
        date: 1524526218641
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: '24/4/2018',
    data: [
      {
        id: 1002,
        orderNo: 'def',
        customer: 'Ringo',
        date: 1524555627191
      },
      {
        id: 1003,
        orderNo: 'ghi',
        customer: 'George',
        date: 1524555662611
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: '25/4/2018',
    data: [
      {
        id: 1004,
        orderNo: 'jkl',
        customer: 'Paul',
        date: 1524717318641
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For the title sections I use the following function: [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

I think I could use the array method [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) but I have not managed to create the desired structure

Comment: Give it a try man.

Comment: You will need to iterate manually through the group if you want to group the `data` object based on `date`.

Answer (score 6):

use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1001,
    orderNo: 'abc',
    customer: 'John',
    date: 1524526218641
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    orderNo: 'def',
    customer: 'Ringo',
    date: 1524555627191
  },
  {
    id: 1003,
    orderNo: 'ghi',
    customer: 'George',
    date: 1524555662611
  },
  {
    id: 1004,
    orderNo: 'jkl',
    customer: 'Paul',
    date: 1524717318641
  }
]
let res = data.reduce((re, o) => {  
  let existObj = re.find(
    obj => obj.title === new Date(o.date).toLocaleDateString()
  )

  if (existObj) {
    existObj.data.push(o)
  } else {
    re.push({
      title: new Date(o.date).toLocaleDateString(),
      data: [o]
    })
  }
  return re
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: sadly, this will not work. He wants to group it if dates are the same.

Comment: @user1496463,sorry for my blind,updated now ,please check it